# Using RestSharp (or any JSON Post) to Asp.Net Membership JsonResult return (MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, xamarin.ios, forms-authentication

From a browser, I can call an MVC controller like ../Account/Login with post parameters username and password and the browser plants a cookie such that on subsequent calls I do not need to pass in credentials for my [authorized] calls like /Account/GetUser to work.

I'm trying to do the same thing from a MonoTouch app (I think it would be the same issue from a windows forms app) and even though my /Account/Login call works, the subsequent calls act as if they are not authenticated.   I assume it is because I'm not a browser and I don't have all that plumbing.  True?

So, my questions is, using simple ASP.NET and forms auth, is there a way that I can get my Monotouch app to behave in a similar way to a browser app that stores a cookie?

All Suggestions (including ... dumb question) are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I assume it's just a typo, but the correct attribute is `[Authorize]`

Comment: Yes.  You need to manually get the auth cookies from the Response stream and include them in any subsequent Requests you make.

Comment: thanks. that is what I thought. I was hoping there was some clever way to have this happen automatically.